# Xamarin-Monogame cross platform on Windows, using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform, monogame

I am trying to organize my Monogame project in a way which would simplify cross-platform targeting. However, since I am working on Windows, Xamarin Studio doesn't offer the "Monogame Universal App" or "Monogame/iOS" templates, but only [templates for Shared projects and Android projects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/monogame/introduction/part1/):

> Xamarin Studio on Windows does not include iOS templates. Developers working on Windows need to add all code files to a project-specific Android project or manually add either a PCL or shared code project.

Since this is a Monogame project, I feel like most of the game logic and drawing should be abstracted through Monogame classes. But if I create a new Android solution in Xamarin studio, it creates a single project which contains the main `Activity` along with the `Game` class which references `Mono.Android` and `OpenTK` directly. Furthermore, included `About*.txt` files imply that I should be accessing resources through designer-built `Resource` class, which is tied directly to Android.

OTOH, if I create a "shared Monogame Xamarin project" in Xamarin Studio, it's completely empty (only a `Game1` template class, but not even a reference to monogame, so it doesn't compile at all).

**Is there a walkthrough/template for creating a shared Monogame project, with content which can be processed differently for each target platform?**

Comment: Did you check whether Visual Studio contains the templates? Based on the code base, https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/tree/develop/ProjectTemplates/VisualStudio2015 the installer should configure VS with the bits.

Comment: Well, Monogame contains VS templates for Android, iOS and Windows Universal Apps, but they are not configured to share code. Xamarin, on the other hand, also has VS templates which *do* share code, but don't include Monogame references, so I am not sure how to configure the shared content pipeline (nor which Monogame reference to add to the shared project, because Monogame has different nuget packages for each platform. Third option is outside VS, using Xamarin Studio, but there I only have a single target (Android, or Windows) because it's a Windows limitation.

Comment: @LexLi: I think [Monogame samples/2D platformer](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame.Samples/tree/develop/Platformer2D) might be a good starting point, I noticed it supports multiple targets.